# How Get Frontmost Sequence of Processes ? - Applescript / Swift / Objetive-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, automation, applescript

If you Press Command + Tab and hold, you can see the Sequence of Frontmost Processes

at AppleScript you can Access the First Frontmost Process

Code Example:

`Tell application "System Events" to get first process whose frontmost is true`

but you can't access all sequence of frontmost ( or I don't know how )

And here is the question: How I Can Access the sequence that is showed when Command + Tab is pressed ?

Obs: Command + Tab is called Application Switcher

Comment: Why do you need that sequence? What significance do you think it has?

Comment: This doesn't give you their order but does return the names of the apps you see when pressing **⌘-Tab**: `tell application "System Events" to get name of every process whose background only is false`